# ROS .msg depends

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two packages: inpub and insub

in  inpub CmakeList.txt

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  insub
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs)

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES inpub
# CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

in .xml

```
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
<build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
<build_depend>insub</build_depend>
<build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
<run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
<run_depend>insub</run_depend>
<run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
<run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
```

1. 

When I in inpub.py

```
import insub
```

A take error

```
File "/home/slavaglaps/two/src/test/scripts/inpub.py", line 6, in <module>
    import insub
ImportError: No module named insub
```

How can I import it correctly?

2)
In the insub package I have inpub/msg/TwoInts.msg

How do I transfer this class?
I also read in the documentation about a separate package for .msg. Can you talk more about this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259619/ros-.msg-depends/) by [slavaglaps](https://answers.ros.org/users/30079/slavaglaps/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-04-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to help cmake generate your messages you need to have some declarations on your CMakeLists.txt
For example, for insub you should have something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(insub)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)

add_message_files(
  FILES
  TwoInts.msg
)

generate_messages(
    DEPENDENCIES
    std_msgs
)

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS std_msgs)
```

Of course this is just a speculation, but it would most definitely work for you. Also, you will have to create the corresponding package.xml file, just like you've done for inpub.

Good luck!

P.S. The "no module named insub" error could be due to wrong or non-existent CMakeLists.txt and package.xml for insub, or wrong catkin workspace configuration. Check if you have these lines inside your ~/.bashrc:

```
source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash
```

and

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) with karma: 641 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1